# Rule based expert system that helps with implementation phase

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system

I need examples of Rule Based Expert Systems for the implementation phase of the software engineering, 
I have found out about Pyke, but Im not really sure if it is an Expert System...can anyone give me an example of what a RBES for implementation really is?

Comment: Interesting question, but probably off-topic here.

Comment: Do you want to use one, implement one yourself or is it just out of curiosity? I'm asking because this is almost a forgotten research topic (to my knowledge at least) and you question is a little broad.

Comment: Is for an investigation I have to do and also curiosity

Comment: [Wikipedia: CLIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS) (NASA's AI Language, 1985) is certainly an important persona (expert system shell, supports rule based reasoning, it's source code is open) in the world of [Wikipedia: Production rule systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_system)

Answer (score 3):

There is a distinction between expert system tools and expert systems. [Pyke](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/) is a tool (python module) that can be used to implement expert systems.  Similarly, [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) - as its website states - is "A Tool for Building Expert Systems" but it is not itself an expert system. Expert system tools such as PyKE, CLIPS, [JESS](http://jessrules.com/), [drools](http://drools.org), etc. typically provide a language for defining expert systems, as well as a compiler or interpreter within which the system can be efficiently executed.

If you are interested in examples of expert systems implemented with some of these tools, most of them will have examples provided (or linked) on their web sites. You can find some examples of relatively simple systems implemented with CLIPS [here](http://courses.washington.edu/css482/examples/).